# How to select a random line from a file and print it in python? And whats a AttributeError: __exit__?

Tags: python, file, printing

I ma using python for a school project and I have these two files:

```
file = open("Songs.txt","r") 
file = open("Artists.txt","r")
```

And I wish to select a random artist from my Artists file then print it.

```
import random
with "Artists.txt":
    ARTIST = random.randint(0,9)
    print(ARTIST)
```

It also keeps showing a AttributeError: **exit** and says:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "N:\1GCSE\Computing\Programming Project\Project.py", line 26, in  with "Artists.txt":
>   AttributeError: _exit _

What do i do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in your usage of `with`. When using the `with` statement, you have to supply an execution that returns something, together with a variable defined by `as`:

```
with process as foo:
    do_something
```

This evaluates `process`, calls the `__enter__` method on the return value (which is called a "context guard"), and assigns the return value of `__enter__` to the variable `foo`. Afterwards, `do_something` is executed and, no matter what happens, the `__exit__` method of the guard object is called. See more [here](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm), where this explanation was taken from.
So you can't simply use `with` with your filename, like you did in your code.

If i get this correctly, your artist.txt file has 10 lines with different artists, and you're trying to randomly select one of those lines and print it. You could, for example, do the following:

```
import random

with open('artists.txt', 'r') as file:
    ARTIST = random.randint(0, 9)
    print(file.readlines()[ARTIST])
```

which does effectively the same as

```
import random

file = open('artists.txt', 'r')
ARTIST = random.randint(0, 9)
print(file.readlines()[ARTIST])
file.close()
```

but is safer and more effective, since the file is closed automatically right after executing your code.

This will read all the lines in your file, put them in a list, select a random number between 0 and 9 and print the object in the list at that Position, giving you a random artist from your file.

Comment: Glad i could help you :) please consider accepting my answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that each line in your `txt` file has artist name. So you should read your file line-by-line then store them in a `list`. Then pick the element of the list randomly.

**Note:** `.readlines()` is compatible with python 3x

You can try this:

```
import random

def read_file():
    with open('file.txt') as fp:
        lines = fp.readlines()
    print(random.choice(lines))
    # If you want to return the randomly picked artist, you can uncomment following code
    # return random.choice(lines)
```